# Laravel inject sentry user into model

Tags: laravel, testing, dependency-injection

I keen to make my code decouple and ready for testing.

I have an Eloquent model getBudgetConvertedAttribute is depend on sentry user attribute.

```
public function getBudgetConvertedAttribute()
{
    return Sentry::getUser()->currency * $this->budget;
}
```

This throw error while testing because Sentry::getUser is return null.

My question is, How shall I code to inject user into model from controller or service provider binding or testing?

Answer (score 0):

Inject a $sentry object as a dependency in the constructor instead of using the Sentry Facade.

Example

```
 use Path\To\Sentry;
 class ClassName
 {
   protected $sentry
   public function __construct(Sentry $sentry)
   {
      $this->sentry = $sentry;
   }

   public function methodName() 
   {

    $this->sentry->sentryMethod();

   }
 }
```

Comment: I think that too. But Eloquent Model use facade like static method. E.g. ClassName::with()->where()->get()->limit(); In this case it throw error say that construction expect Sentry but It pass in null. I still looking further on how to make it work

Comment: Something might be wrong with the query. Did you try dd(Sentry::getUser()->currency * $this->budget); to see the output? What's the error / exception that you get (if you get any)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a method on the model, then takes a Sentry user object as a parameter?

```
public function getBudgetConverted(SentryUser $user)
{
    return $user->currency * $this->budget;
}
```

You’ll need to change the type-hint (`SentryUser`) to the actual name of your user class.

If this is to aid testing, you could go one step furhter and type-hint on an interface (which you should be any way), that way you could test your method with a mock user object rather than one that may have a load of other dependencies like a database connection, which Eloquent models do.

Comment: sorry, I'm using Laravel 4 doesn't support method injection. And for eloquent attribute, I do not call this function directly. but with $model->budgetConverted; this is going to resolve to this function.

Comment: I work on Laravel 5 on some project too, I know the concept of code to interface, but how do I mock the user on the testing env? as I said, I do not call the method and pass in the $user by myself. it is resolving by some binding method.